# Implementing bcrypt in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, bcrypt

I'm trying to use bcrypt with Angular7 to store an encrypted password in MySQL.

I have used `npm install bcrypt` to install bcrypt and importing it like so
`import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';`.

Everything is compiling fine till this point; it fails to do so when I add `bcrypt.hash()`

The entire code for the login.component.ts file is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

loginForm : FormGroup;
success = false;
loginFailed = false;

constructor(private formBuilder : FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() : void {

    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}

DoLogin()
{
    console.log(this.loginForm.value);

    pass = bcrypt.hash('Pass@123', 10); // App is not compliling when I add this line //
}
```

How do I call the methods in bcrypt?

Comment: The bcrypt methods are *asynchronous*, you need to pass a callback or resolve the promise.

Comment: Why are you encrypting on the client side?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you please provide me with an example, I am new to Angular.

Comment: It's not really anything to do with Angular, the bcrypt docs show how to interact with their API.

Comment: @JonasPraem I am learning Angular and my goal is to encrypt the password before sending it to my API (python) which will store the encrypted password to the DB.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you mean this: bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
  // Store hash in your password DB.
});

Tried this as well it does not compile.

Comment: Yes, that's the callback usage.

Comment: Tried again but it won't compile. I'm getting the following error:

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../package' in 'D:\1833\Projs\ng\ng-materialUI\node_modules\node-gyp\lib'

Comment: I think it is easiest to use bcryptjs - https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs ... bcrypt appears to be designed for use in NodeJS.

Comment: Thanks for the info; will check that out.

Answer (score 12):

You can install bcryptjs (`npm install bcryptjs`) and use the following code:

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
pass = bcrypt.hashSync(this.loginForm.value.password, salt);
```

Your code must look like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

loginForm : FormGroup;
success = false;
loginFailed = false;

constructor(private formBuilder : FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() : void {

    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}

DoLogin()
{
    console.log(this.loginForm.value);

    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    pass = bcrypt.hashSync('Pass@123', salt);
}
```

After that, if you get an `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'...` error, you must add this code into package.json file:

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false,
    "crypto": false,
    "stream": false,
    "http": false,
    "tls": false,
    "zlib": false,
    "https": false,
    "net": false
  }
```

Comment: Hi sir i have a question , i implemented bcryptjs in my angular app also i knew that spring also is using Bcrypt for hashing the password but i dont get the same result any explanation ? thank u .

Comment: @CHARFEDDINEAmine I'm not really experienced with this but check if you are providing the same number of salt "rounds" to both Spring and Angular. As you can see he is providing 10 rounds of salting to Angular app, and as far as I know default value for salting is 12, so you maybe need to change salting in Angular or Spring app.

Answer (score 1):

### Your way of using bcrypt in your Angular app.

First of all, alone installing bcrypt using "npm install bcrypt" for angular app won't work.
Because bcrypt it self has 2 dependency like,

1. node-pre-gyp
2. Native Abstractions for Node.js

### If you install these two then your application may work with bcrypt.

My way of using bcrypt for Angular app.
I have installed the bcrypt-js using "npm install bcryptjs --save".

NODE.js
On node.js, the inbuilt crypto module's randomBytes interface is used to obtain secure random numbers.

BROWSER
In the browser, bcrypt.js relies on Web Crypto API's getRandomValues interface to obtain secure random numbers. If no cryptographically secure source of randomness is available, you may specify one through bcrypt.setRandomFallback.

As we are using for browser so, Angulars node.js does not have a module called "crypto", because bcrypt needs a module to create a secure random number with this crypto module, so you will get a warning in your application "crypto" module not found.

To get rid of from this warning you should go to this file location in you project,
D:\<>\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js, line no: 70.

either you comment that or you place that try block below the second try block.

In that code what is happening is, first the bcrypt is trying the generate the random number from "crypt" module, if it is not, then it is going to use web api to generate the secure random number, this is the url: https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-WebCryptoAPI-20170126/.

or you can write your own logic to provide the random number but that won't be secure enough.

I hope you understand.

Please ping me if you have any doubt.

Comment: what is `2- Native Abstractions for Node.js`?

Answer (score 0):

You can install *** npm install bcryptjs *** from the terminal. With this you will get the libraries of bcryptjs. 
The next step is to change your old one ( **import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';** ) to the new one: 
 **import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';** 
Use the same methods and it gave me no problems.

 Example:

```
    if ((user == users[i].username) && (bcrypt.compareSync(pass, users[i].password))) ok = true;
```

Comment: Have a principle KISS, keep it simple, and this "if" statement are too complex, must simplify most as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sha.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha.js) : rest is up to you :)

```
npm install --save sha.js

import * as shajs from 'sha.js';

shajs('sha256').update({stringToBeHashed}).digest('hex')
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use **npm install bcryptjs --save** instead of **npm install bcrypt --save**

bcryptjs not giveng error, so you can use this in angular